# PHP order by value in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array in the below format:

```
Array
(
    [123451000] => Array
        (
            [total] => 70
            [total_tech] => 36
            [duration] => 300
        )

    [123451001] => Array
        (
            [total] => 9
            [total_tech] => 3
            [duration] => 197
        )

    [123451002] => Array
        (
            [total] => 103
            [total_tech] => 97
            [duration] => 273
        )
)
```

I am looping through it, but wondered if it is possible to order by the `total`?

**EDIT:** My current foreach loop

```
foreach($agents as $agent => $option) {
    //$talktime = secondsToTime($x["talktime_sum"]);
    $display.= '<tr>
    <td>'.get_dtypes('phone', $agent).'</td>
    <td>'.number_format($option["total_calls"]).'</td>
    <td>'.number_format($option["technical_calls"]).'</td>
    <td>'.number_format($option["sales_calls"]).'</td>
    <td>'.number_format($option["other_calls"]).'</td>
    <td>'.$option["total_duration"].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['total'] <=> $b['total'];
});
```

`usort` is a function that sorts an array with quick sort, using a user given function for the comparison.

~~`uksort` is a variant of it, that keeps the array's keys~~

`<=>` is the "spaceship" operator, it returns `-1` if the left side is bigger, `1` if the rigth side is bigger, and `0` if they're equal.

**Edit**
The `uksort` sorts **using the key**, not keeping the key.
`uasort` is the one that sorts with the values and also keeps the array keys

Comment: see my update - do i replace my current foreach loop with your code - using the `uasort` function?

Comment: You use your loop to print it, use sorting to sort the array before you print